# Can I edit Magento 2 LESS files from the Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: magento2, frontend, less, chrome-browser, workflow

I had a pretty comfortable workflow in Magento 1 where I've added the 'skin' directory to the workplace in Chrome Dev Tools and could edit the CSS files right from the Dev Tools. Is something like that possible with LESS and Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can edit Magento 2 LESS files from the Chrome Dev Tools but could not edit the CSS files directly from the Dev Tools.To make permanent changes to Magento 2 LESS files, it's better to edit the source files directly in your development environment.

You can locate the LESS files in your Magento 2 theme directory under app/design/frontend/your_vendor/your_theme/web/css/source. After making changes, you'll need to compile the LESS files to CSS either by using Magento's built-in mechanisms (bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy) or by using a developer mode with automatic compilation enabled.

Directly editing files in the Chrome Dev Tools can be useful for quick experimentation or debugging, but for long-term changes, it's essential to edit the source files in a proper development environment.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got you. Thing is with Magento 1 I could make permanent changes to source files in the filesystem directly from the Dev Tools.